# Sample code for dropdown box in javascript

Tags: javascript

Happy Saturday community, i've been building my first website and have learned tons about css,javascript,php,mvc framework and much more. Can anyone help me with a dropdown box like some of the bootsrap examples.... something like

```
 ---------------------------
 |      HEADER            +| 

 ---------------------------

 ---------------------------
 |      HEADER            -|
 ---------------------------
 ---------------------------
 ---------------------------
----------------------------
```

**EDIT:**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu"> 
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li> 
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li> 
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li> 
    <li class="divider"></li> 
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li> 
</ul>
```

when expanded ???

Comment: Please share the code you might have tried and ask a [specific question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: `    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>` I only know how to get a regular drop down menu as if you clicked a button on menu bar at the top of browser. However i want simply a title with a '+' in it that expands to a drop down list..
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>

Comment: why not use bootstrap if you know about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using jQuery. But the main idea is to toggle the display property on an element inside your header `<div>`, such as the `<ul>` that you might use to make a navbar.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Kk78h/ (Make sure to click on the '+' sign.)

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>Header <span id="adjust">+</span></h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Nav1</li><li>Nav2</li><li>Nav3</li><li>Nav4</li>
    </ul>
</div>

#header { width: 500px;}
h1 { text-align: center; }
h1 #adjust {vertical-align: super; font-size: 20px; color: red; cursor: pointer;}
ul { height: 100px; list-style: none; display: none;}
li { float: left; width: 25%;}

$('#adjust').click(function() {
    $('ul').toggle();
    var cval = $('#adjust').html();
    $('#adjust').html(cval == '+' ? '-' : '+');                                 
});
```